# Trying to generate a pdf using Snappy (wkhtmltopdf wrapper)

Tags: wkhtmltopdf

I'm trying to generate a pdf using snappy through this code:

```
$snappy = new SnappyPdf;

$snappy->setExecutable('/usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf');

$snappy->save('http://www.google.com', '/tmp/jander.pdf');
```

In the apache log i find this:

> Done Loading pages (1/6) [>
>   ] 0% [======>
>   ] 10% [==========>
>   ] 18% [============>
>   ] 20% [=============>
>   ] 22% [===============>
>   ] 25% [================>
>   ] 28% [==================>
>   ] 30% [===================>
>   ] 33% [=====================>
>   ] 35% [======================>
>   ] 37% [=========================>
>   ] 43% [===========================>
>   ] 46%
>   [============================================================] 100% Counting pages (2/6)
>   [============================================================] Object 1 of 1 Resolving links (4/6)
>   [============================================================] Object 1 of 1 Loading headers and
>   footers (5/6) Printing pages (6/6) [> 
>   ] Preparing
>   [============================================================] Page 1 of 1 Done

but the pdf is not generated.

Any idea?

Javier

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you start by looking at the return value from `$snappy->save()`. According to the [code](https://github.com/knplabs/snappy/blob/master/src/SnappyMedia.php), it will return true if the outputted PDF file is created and the file is not empty.

You might also want to check the output of `$this->buildCommand($url, $path)` on line 37 of the [code](https://github.com/knplabs/snappy/blob/master/src/SnappyMedia.php). Try manually executing this code on your server.

Answer (score 1):

use `$snappy->generate`

or

`$snappy->generateFromHtml($htmlstring, 'path/to/save/file')`